# canvas getContext returning WebGL2RenderingContext and RenderingContext. Typescript issue

Tags: typescript, canvas, webgl

I am currently learning typescript and I have come across an issue I dont understand. I am trying to detect if the browser supports webgl. You detect it by creating a canvas object on the document and then getting the context to see if it is "webgl" or "experimental-webgl". If it does support webgl it will return WebGlRenderingContext object otherwise null as can be seen here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext

So I have this:

```
const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
const gl : WebGL2RenderingContext | null = canvas.getContext( 'webgl',contextOptions ) || canvas.getContext( 'experimental-webgl', contextOptions );
```

The problem is that getContext actually returns a RenderingContext which is a helper type and not a real type. So my VS Code IDE is shouting at me as the "gl" valriable isnt type WebGLRenderingContext according to the type specification. However, with the parameters I am passing it will be either WebGLRenderingContext or null and never RenderingContext, I am calling functions on my gl variable like "getParamerter" and also getShaderPrecisionFormat which are functions on WebGLRenderingContext but not RenderingContext.

As I said im currently learning typescript so I am probably missing some basic information here. I am not sure how to make IDE confortable with the fact that according to the canvas API doc it will be a WebGLRenderingContext and not the RenderingContext it thinks it will be.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of casting you can make the returned type more specific. Typescript offers two ways of type-casting.

Note that the following code is requesting a WebGL**2** context, your original example was annotating a `WebGL2RenderingContext` yet requested a `WebGLRenderingContext`. I also removed the experimental context fallback as there's no such thing for WebGL**2**.

### The 'as' keyword

Simply add **as** and the desired type after the value.
e.g.

```
const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
const gl: WebGL2RenderingContext | null = canvas.getContext('webgl2') as WebGL2RenderingContext;
```

### Angle-brackets

The above can also be written in angle-brackets syntax. This means enclosing the desired type within **<>** and prepending it to the value.
e.g.

```
const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
const gl: WebGL2RenderingContext | null = <WebGL2RenderingContext> canvas.getContext('webgl2');
```

### About Experimental WebGL

The experimental webgl context is from when webgl was actively developed and browsers just implemented it, it was a stop gap before implementations and the API specification were mature, eventually `"experimental-webgl"` became `"webgl"`, that was over a decade ago, pre arrow-functions, fetch API, ES6. If you don't explicitly need to support a platform like that I'd advise against having a fallback to experimental webgl.